# Discrete Math: How do I proof this problem by the ​Proof by contradiction?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have been trying to solve this proof of sets but I keep getting something other than he result it can you please how me how I would go about solve this problem?

[image: Here is the problem]

Comment: You said you have been working on this but get stuck. Can you show us your attempt?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see you needed a proof by contradiction.

For this *not* to be true you either need an $x \in Q_2$ but $x \not\in Q_1$, or an $x \in Q_1$ but $x \not\in Q_1$.

Case 1: Suppose $x \in Q_1 \not \implies x \in Q_2$.

Then there is an $x \in Q_1$ but $x \not \in Q_2$.

So $x = m/n; m, n \in Z$. Let $d = \gcd(n,m)\ne 1$ because $x \not \in Q_2$ then $m = dm'$ for some integer $m'$ and $n = dn'$ for some integer $n'$. So $ x = m/n = m'd/n'd = m'/n'$ but $x \not \in Q_2$ so $e=\gcd(m',n') \ne 1$.  So $m'=em''$ and $n' = en''$.  So $n= edn''$ and $m=edm''$ and $e*d > d$ is a common divisor.  So $d$ *not* the greatest common divisor after all.

So that's a contradiction. So $x\in Q_1 \implies x \in Q_2$.

Suppose $x\in Q_2 \not \implies x\in Q_1$.

Then there is an $x \in Q_2$ so that $x \not \in Q_2$.  So $x = a/b; a\in Z,b\in Z; \gcd(a,b) = 1$.  But $x\not \in Q_1 $ so $a$ and $b$ can not both be integers.  But I just *said* they were.  So that's a contradiction.

So $x \in Q_2 \implies x \in Q_1$.

So the two definitions are equivalent.

===== old answer ===

Prove if $x \in \mathbb Q_1$ then $x \in \mathbb Q_2$.  That proves that $\mathbb Q_1 \subset \mathbb Q_2$.

Then prove if $y \in \mathbb Q_2$ then $y \in \mathbb Q_1$.  That proves that $\mathbb Q_2 \subset \mathbb Q_1$

And that proves that $\mathbb Q_1 = \mathbb Q_2$.

Hint: if $m = m'\gcd(m,n)$ and $n = n'\gcd(m,n)$ then  $\frac {m}{n} = \frac {m'*\gcd(m,n)}{n'*\gcd(m,n)}= \frac {m'}{n'}$

Comment: what would be the final result?

Comment: i am completyl confsued

Comment: If x = a/b gcd(a,b)=1 then let m =a and n = b and x = m/n so Q2 => Q1.  If x = m/n then reduce it to lowest terms to get x = a/b in lowest terms. So Q1 => Q2.

Comment: Oh... i didn't see you needed a contradiction.  I'll change....